# UITableView - moveRowAtIndexPath causes memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, nsindexpath, uitableview

**Overview**

- In an iOS project, I have a `UITableView` and I am trying to move a row of the UITableView.
- In my model, the order of data has been changed, so I am trying to visually show it in the table, that is why I have used `UITableView`'s method `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`
- In order to do so I have created an `NSIndexPath` instance which I am passing to the UITableView's method.

**When the leak accurs**

- When you create an NSIndexPath instance using the method `indexPathForRow: section:` (as shown in the code section) and then pass it to the `UITableView`'s method `moveRowAtIndexPath: toIndexPath:` it leaks.

**Note:**

- I am using ARC (automatic reference counting)
- XCode 4.3.1
- I used the Instruments (Xcode menu - Product > Profile) to determine the memory leak

**Code: (inside UITableViewController)**

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRow inSection:0]; //leaking

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:originalIndexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath]; //I think this causes the leak
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

**Steps I have tried**

- Commenting out the call to the method `moveRowAtIndexPath:originalIndexPath toIndexPath:`, prevents the memory leak
- I have manually used `CFRelease` (not sure this is a good practice in an Automatic Reference Counting environment)

  **CFRelease((__bridge void *)toIndexPath);**

**Questions:**

- Why does this occur ? is there any solution to it ?
- Is instrument's memory leak results accurate ?
- Is there a bug in  UITableView's method `moveRowAtIndexPath:originalIndexPath toIndexPath:` ?
- Is CFRelease an option ? Is there a safe way to prevent the app from crashing in case CFRelease tries to release a memory that has been already released (see exact code above).

Comment: I'm not sure if Instruments would indicate a memory leak if the object has been dereferenced but not garbage collected, which is why this is a comment and not an answer. Have you tried running [[NSGarbageCollector defaultInstance] collectExhaustively] after the updates?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am doing a iOS project, so I wouldn't be able to try garbage collection. correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted should not result in a memory leak in an ARC setup (nor should it without ARC for that matter).

If you indeed suspect a bug (such as that the UITableView fails to release the NSIndexPath object), you could probably try to manually release it as a temporary workaround. However, are you sure that it is just not releasing it after the animations are complete? Even if you have no animations, it may be that the indexPath object is not released until hitting the idle loop (it is quite common with GUI components, and obviously also with autoreleased objects).

However, in order to confirm that it is indeed a leak, try to investigate if the memory increases with time in the long run (it may be that the UITableView sticks to its latest indexPath object, in which it would probably not be a problem). Also, try to run the debugger with the NSZombieEnabled environment variable set. This will detect and break into the debugger when you try to double-release an object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I am caught up with another issue, I will try NSZombieEnabled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment, so I'll have to add an answer. I also see this leak. I am NOT using ARC, and I am not using beginUpdates/endUpdates to wrap the single call to moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: Instruments claims a 32 byte leak of the NSIndexPath whenever I call this method.

The call to NSIndexPath's indexPathForRow:inSection: should return an auto-released object that does not need to be manually freed. I suspect moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: is incorrectly retaining the object, causing the leak.

I added some debug code to log the retainCount of the NSIndexPath before and after the call to  moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: and got 1 before (it's on an auto-release pool so that's expected) and 5 afterwards (definitely not expected unless it has been added to the auto-release pool 4 more times!)

Edit: See also https://devforums.apple.com/message/639904 (requires Apple Developer account)